Can the Attorney General, with a cooperating president, naturalize all undocumented immigrants?
If according to 8 U.S. Code § 1421 the "sole authority to naturalize persons as citizens of the United States is conferred upon the Attorney General." What are restrictions placed on the Attorney General? Is it really as simple as that statue makes it out to be? Can he for example,

Solicit any willing eligible court to begin administering Oaths of Allegiance
Issue mass "Certificates of Eligibility" for potential applicants to the courts, concurrently along with signed "Certificates of Naturalization"
Upon applicants swearing the oath of allegiance and receiving signed Certificates of Naturalization they're naturalized citizen of the United States which is only revocable if they committed a misrepresentation or omission?


This question was inspired by comments by phoog

No. The statute sets out requirements for naturalization, and does not allow anyone to be naturalized that does not meet the requirements set out in statute. The statutes regarding naturalization are in various sections of 8 USC chapter 12 subchapter III part II. The main requirements of naturalization (including continuous residence after admission as a permanent resident (green card holder) for 5 years, physical presence for half that period, good moral character for that period, and attachment to the Constitution) are in 8 USC 1427, which says:

(a) Residence
No person, except as otherwise provided in this subchapter, shall be
naturalized unless such applicant, (1) immediately preceding the date
of filing his application for naturalization has resided continuously,
after being lawfully admitted for permanent residence, within the
United States for at least five years and during the five years
immediately preceding the date of filing his application has been
physically present therein for periods totaling at least half of that
time, and who has resided within the State or within the district of
the Service in the United States in which the applicant filed the
application for at least three months, (2) has resided continuously
within the United States from the date of the application up to the
time of admission to citizenship, and (3) during all the periods
referred to in this subsection has been and still is a person of good
moral character, attached to the principles of the Constitution of the
United States, and well disposed to the good order and happiness of
the United States.

The wording "No person, except as otherwise provided in this subchapter, shall be naturalized unless such applicant [...]" means that the Executive Branch has no power to naturalize someone if the requirements are not met, unless otherwise provided in the statute.
Additional requirements for needing to pass English and civics testing are in 8 USC 1423, which likewise says, "No person except as otherwise provided in this subchapter shall hereafter be naturalized as a citizen of the United States upon his own application who cannot demonstrate [...]".
There are of course modifications or exceptions to the requirements in various cases, like for the spouses of US citizens (in 8 USC 1430) or for members and veterans of the US military (in 8 USC 1439 and 8 USC 1440). But in all such cases the modifications or exceptions must be explicitly provided by statute, since, again, 8 USC 1427 does not allow naturalization for people who do not meet the requirements, unless otherwise provided elsewhere in the statutes.
There is a small amount of leeway for the executive branch in administering the requirements for naturalization, e.g. in determining the format of English and civics testing, in the rules for what constitutes good moral character, or in determining whether continuous residence is interrupted by absences of between 6 months and 1 year. And even those often require going through the process to propose and accept comments on new regulations, which can take years. But the majority of the main requirements are objective, e.g. whether the person has been admitted as a permanent resident, whether the person has had the requisite periods of continuous residence (if it was determined that it was not interrupted) and physical presence, etc., and the Executive Branch has no power or discretion to waive requirements if they were objectively not met.

No
The AG only has the authority that the law grants them. So, if you keep reading, you will see that there are things that make a person eligible and ineligible. Some of these requirements can be waived at the AG’s discretion but many can’t.
Even for those that can, the law requires positive discretion to be exercised on a case-by-case basis - blanket approvals are not allowed. Action by the government needs case-by-case discretion, inaction doesn’t.

You keep saying "the law" but this answer doesn't cite anything. I gave "the law" that seems to empower the AG without limitation. What "law" limits "the person's" eligibility?  What can the AG not waive according "the law"? Where does "the law" say "blanket approvals are not allowed"? I came here looking for the law. I have no doubt the law could say that, but I'm trying to understand what it does say, and without those details -- at least provide the citation that I can read.

I said “keep reading”. You have to read the whole law, not just one part of it.

@EvanCarroll Just "keep reading." The U.S. Code is only 20 million words long, so you'll find the answer eventually. Until you get there, just assume that this answer is right because he said so.

@EvanCarroll A cooperating President and AG can massively reduce the bar for naturalization and order to speed roll all applications that do qualify for waivers with waivable conditions handled by Date X. As for the relevant Code: you'd just need to read USC 8: "Aliens and Nationality."

@EvanCarroll 8 USC chapter 6 (8 USC 100-117, 131-175, 201-239) are approximately 120.000 words on Immigration and should cover most of the laws you might want to read up on. And then you might also need to read up on the rules and policies of the USCIS, who handle the applications 99% of the way.

Sole authority does not mean plenary authority, even though in ordinary usage it connotes so. "Sole" implies only "only", i.e., to the exclusion of other officials or institutions; the Attorney General must still act under the legal order of the United States that requires everyone (even the AG) to follow the law. The same section provides:

(d) Sole procedure
A person may only be naturalized as a citizen of the United States in the manner and under the conditions prescribed in this subchapter and not otherwise.

The "sole authority" language, introduced in the Immigration Act of 1990, was used to remove authorities from the various courts, who held the power of naturalization, and instead transfer this power (authority) to the Attorney General, who became the only official responsible for the naturalization decision of aliens. The naturalization thus transformed from a judicial decision to an administrative one.
